# Simple text sliding animation for website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been practicing web development for the last couple of months, and I want to try adding some flare to a portfolio site.
I have a header with my name, and I want to animate the 'b e n' and the 'u s t e d' coming out from the L (or the '|' in this case). Should I do this through code, or is there a norm for this kind of task?

[Logo that I want to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16AH.png)

Comment: Do you want it to look like typing, one whole character revealed at a time, or a smooth reveal of the word (going backwards in the case of Ben). And please put the code you have so far in your question.

Comment: @AHaworth I want it to be a smooth like to unveil the rest of the letters. The only code i have right now is a bunch of <span>'s for each letter. I was thinking about using :before/:after to shrink a shape horizontally. But I need the 'b' to slide back to make space for the 'en'.

Comment: So you want the 'b' to be revealed next to the L then the 'b' to move to the left and an 'e' appears next to the 'L' then the 'be' moves left and a 'n' appears next to the L. Is that right? Wrapping in spans is probably going to be helpful. Please put your code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to put the name into a 3 column grid so that the 'l' stays in the same place as the other items are animating.

As you want a smooth reveal rather than a typewriter effect it's not necessary to animate each character individually.

This snippet puts them into another element and animates that. The left hand one goes from right to left and the right hand one from left to right by increasing the width from 0.

Note: this snippet cheats in a way as it uses a monospace font. For a variable font then you can use the same technique but need to make some decisions about how much space to allow each column.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3ch 1ch 5ch;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 4em;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.reverse {
  text-align: right;
}

.reverse span {
  --w: 3ch;
  right: 0;
}

.forwards span {
  --w: 5ch;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: var(--w);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="reverse">
    <span>ben</span>
  </div>
  <div class="l">L</div>
  <div class="forwards">
    <span>usted</span>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Hmm, my 'usted' is sliding the same direction as the 'ben'. Must be a rule in my code somewhere.

Comment: If you run the code snippet here without moving it into any other code is it OK?

Comment: Yep, works normally in the snippet.

Comment: In your system which is giving the problem can you have a look in your dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied to the forwards element.